# The input data is not a complete block decrypt c#

Tags: c#, aes

I'm trying to Decrypt some data I used Aes to encrypt and saved on my database.

Here's the complete ENCRYPT Method:

```cs
public static byte[] Encrypt(string simpletext, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] cipheredtext;
    using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
    {
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(simpletext);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }

                cipheredtext = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
    return cipheredtext;
}
```

Then I'm calling it from the controller as:

```cs
[HttpPost("TestarMetodoCartao")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> RecuperarPagamentoAsync([FromBody] string documento)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] key = new byte[16];
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
        var EncryptKey = builder.Configuration["EncryptKey"];
        var EncryptIV = builder.Configuration["EncryptIV"];

        key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(EncryptKey);
        iv = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(EncryptIV);

        CartaoPagamento? cartao = await _repo.Buscar(documento);

        if (cartao != null)
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                bandeira = cartao.BandeiraCartao,
                numero = ManagedAesSample.Decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cartao.NumeroCartao), key, iv),
                mes = ManagedAesSample.Decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cartao.MesValidadeCartao), key, iv),
                ano = ManagedAesSample.Decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cartao.AnoValidadeCartao), key, iv),
                nome = "",
                codigo = ManagedAesSample.Decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cartao.CVV), key, iv),
                fatura = ManagedAesSample.Decrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cartao.NumeroOrcamento), key, iv)
            });
        }
        else
        {
            return NoContent();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

and the Decrypt method is:

```cs
static string Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
    string plaintext = null;
    // Create AesManaged
    using(AesManaged aes = new AesManaged()) {
        // Create a decryptor
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV);
        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipherText)) {
            // Create crypto stream
            using(CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                // Read crypto stream
                using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                plaintext = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

I've already tried to change the decrypt method to

```cs
public static string Decrypt(byte[] cipheredtext, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    byte[] src = cipheredtext;
    byte[] dest = new byte[src.Length];
    using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {

        aes.BlockSize = 128;
        aes.KeySize = 128;
        aes.IV = key;
        aes.Key = iv;
        aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
        // decryption
        using (ICryptoTransform decrypt = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV))
        {
            byte[] decryptedText = decrypt.TransformFinalBlock(src, 0, src.Length);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Based on other posts answers, but still got the same error message, always the "the input data is not a complete block".

Comment: Are you sure that the key and iv used for encryption is exact the same on decryption side ? Kindly edit your post and add a test dataset (plaintext, ciphertext, key and IV), thanks. For ciphertext it could be a good idea to encode the data to base64 or hex encoding.

Comment: Write test code that called the encrypt and then decrypt to make sure the two methods work.  Once working try in you actual code.  Make sure the entire encrypt string is received by the decrypt method.  I usually compare the length of the encrypted string with the length sent to the decrypt method to make sure I didn't loose any data.

Comment: The error message *...the input data is not a complete block...* rather indicates a ciphertext whose length is not a multiple of the block size than an invalid key or IV (an incorrect key would rather return *...padding is invalid and cannot be removed...*). Check if the ciphertext is corrupted somewhere (wrong encoding etc.).

Comment: For me the ciphertexts generated with `Encrypt()` can be decrypted with (the upper) `Decrypt()` (tested with .NET Core 5 and 7), i.e. the problem is not reproducible. Thus: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a complete, executable code with test data, so that the issue is reproducible. Also post the C# version you are using.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when i encrypted the byte[] to a string field then tried decrypting from that byte[] field saved as a string - u would need to change the type from string into bytes with an encoder .. try saving the encpyted string as a byte[] in the class instead.

here is my code for encoding Aes with an example at the end for your pleasure.

```
public static class AesEncryption
{
   public struct AesBuilder : IAesBuilder
   {
       public byte[] key { get; set; }
       public byte[] iv { get; set; }

       public AesBuilder()
       {
           using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
           {
               aes.GenerateKey();
               aes.GenerateIV();
               this.key = aes.Key;
               this.iv = aes.IV;
           }
       }
  }

public interface IAesBuilder
{
     byte[] key { get; set; }
     byte[] iv { get; set; }
}

public static string ToBase64(this byte[] crypto) => System.Convert.ToBase64String(crypto);

public static IAesBuilder GetAESKeys() => new AesBuilder();
public static byte[] Encrypt(this string plainText, IAesBuilder EncryptoData) => Encryption(plainText, EncryptoData);

static byte[] Encryption(string plainText, IAesBuilder aesStorage)
{
    using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
    {
        aes.Key = aesStorage.key;
        aes.IV = aesStorage.iv;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

       using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
       {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                 byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
                 cryptoStream.Write(plainBytes, 0, plainBytes.Length);
                 cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                 return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}

public static string Decrypt(this byte[] encryptedData, IAesBuilder EncryptoData) => Decryption(encryptedData, EncryptoData);

static string Decryption(byte[] encryptedData, IAesBuilder aesStorage)
{
     using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
     {
         aes.Key = aesStorage.key;
         aes.IV = aesStorage.iv;
         ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor();

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
       {
             using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
             {
                  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                  {
                       return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                  }
            }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

and you encrypt and decrypt like this :

```
// simple encode/decode example
string plainText = "This text will be encrypted";

// produce keys
var AESkeys = GetAESKeys();

// encrypt
byte[] encryptedData = plainText.Encrypt(AESkeys);
var encryptoString = encryptedData.ToBase64();

// decrypt
string decryptedText = encryptedData.Decrypt(AESkeys);

// display
WriteLine("Plain Text: " + plainText );
WriteLine("Encrypted Data: " + encryptoString );
WriteLine("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText );
```

if you want to encrypt many times u can do this :-

```
var cryptolist = new List<Test>() { 
new Test { Name = "Ian", DescriptionByte = "blahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "10" },
new Test { Name = "Steve", DescriptionByte = "blasdfdsfdsfsdfb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "5" },
new Test { Name = "John", DescriptionByte = "bsdfsdflahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "20" },
new Test { Name = "Ian", DescriptionByte = "blahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "10" },
new Test { Name = "Steve", DescriptionByte = "blasdfdsfdsfsdfb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "5" },
new Test { Name = "John", DescriptionByte = "bsdfsdflahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "20" },
new Test { Name = "Ian", DescriptionByte = "blahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "10" },
new Test { Name = "Steve", DescriptionByte = "blasdfdsfdsfsdfb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "5" },
new Test { Name = "John", DescriptionByte = "bsdfsdflahb".Encrypt(AESkeys), Height = "20" }};
```

and to decrypt

```
// decrypt
foreach (var rec in cryptolist) rec.Description = $"decrypted : {rec.DescriptionByte.Decrypt(AESkeys)}";
```

then just iterate the list and see what it looks like.

ps. i added the decrypt text so u can see the difference.

the class structure looks like this is if your wondering .

```
public class Test
    {
        public string? Name { get; set; } = default;

        public string? Description { get; set; } = default;

        public byte[]? DescriptionByte { get; set; } = new byte[] { };

        public string? Height { get; set; } = default;

    }
```

dont use encoding.UTF8 ... use ToBase64String() instead ... i have included a method u can use instead.